# jquery off is not triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Is there anything wrong with this code?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if($("#textbox-id-recipient").val()) {
        console.log("In");


        $(document).on("click", "#textbox-id-recipient", function(event) {
            addEmail($(this));
        });

        $('#textbox-id-recipient').trigger('click');

        $("#textbox-id-recipient").off("click");
    }

...
});
```

So, after page refresh, if textbox has something, it will trigger the click event, which trigger the one "on" event, but after that it supposed to take off the event, but somehow, when I manually click the textbox, the on event still triggered

Comment: You never bound an event to that element. You bound it to document...

Comment: I'd be curious to know why you're binding to the `document`. Since you already know the element is there, there doesn't seem any need for event delegation.

Comment: Try removing the handler by using this code. It should work: $(document).off("click", "#textbox-id-recipient")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Review**

Considering this statement:

```
$(document).on("click", "#textbox-id-recipient", function(event) {
    addEmail($(this));
});
```

You're binding a click handler to `document`, which is called when a click event bubbles all the way up from where the click starts.

```
    $('#textbox-id-recipient').trigger('click');
```

This will simulate a click event on your element; if the event is not handled, jQuery makes the event bubble up the element tree via the parents until it reaches `document`.

```
    $("#textbox-id-recipient").off("click");
```

Even though the above click trigger works as expected, `.off()` will only look at the current element, i.e. it doesn't automatically "bubble it up".

**Alternative 1**

Therefore, you should disable the click handler on the same element as where you attached it, i.e.:

```
$(document).off("click", "#textbox-id-recipient");
```

Btw, knowing that identifiers must be unique, you might as well attach the event handler on `#textbox-id-recipient` directly *unless* the element is only added later.

```
$('#textbox-id-recipient').on('click', function(event) {
});
```

**Alternative 2**

Also, if the click should only be handled once, use `.one()`:

```
$('#textbox-id-recipient').one('click', function(event) {
});
```

Or, if you want to use event delegation:

```
$(document).one('click', '#textbox-id-recipient', function(event) {
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
if($("#textbox-id-recipient").val()) {
    console.log("In");

    $("#textbox-id-recipient").one("click", function(event) {
        addEmail($(this));
    });

    $('#textbox-id-recipient').triggerHandler('click');
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PQHQZ/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Bind your event to the element, not the document.

```
$('#textbox-id-recipient').on("click", function(event) {
    addEmail($(this));
});

$('#textbox-id-recipient').trigger('click');

$("#textbox-id-recipient").off("click");
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with binding to the document, so the handler is also bound to dynamically added elements. I know... there can be only one ID on a page. Just saying.

Comment: I didn't say there was anything wrong with binding to the document.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the handler by using this code. It should work:

```
$(document).off("click", "#textbox-id-recipient");
```

Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/yntyF/1/